# If $f^{-1} (\operatorname{int}(B)) \subset \operatorname{int}(f^{-1}(B))$ then $f(\operatorname{cl}(A))\subset \operatorname{cl}(f(A))$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Is this proof correct?

> If $f^{-1} (\operatorname{int}(B)) \subset \operatorname{int}(f^{-1}(B))$ for all $B\subset Y$, then $f(\operatorname{cl}(A))\subset \operatorname{cl}(f(A)).$

As $\operatorname{cl}(A) = \operatorname{int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Fr}(A),$ then $f(\operatorname{cl}(A)) = f(\operatorname{int}(A)) \cup f(\operatorname{Fr}(A))$. Thus

$$f(\operatorname{cl}(A)) = f(\operatorname{int}(A)) \cup f(\operatorname{Fr}(A)) \subset f(A) \cup \operatorname{Fr}(f(A))=\operatorname{cl}(A).$$

But I didn't use the hypothesis, and I am not sure if this is true $f(\operatorname{Fr}(A)) \subset \operatorname{Fr}(f(A))$.

Comment: Take $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow S^1$ defined by $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$. And let $A=[0,2\pi]$. Then the boundary of $A$ is $\{0,2\pi\}$, whose image is $\{(1,0)\}$. But the boundary of $f(A)$ is empty.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks @JoséCarlosSantos